# How to Looping Array on PHP and save to database

Tags: php, arrays, database

I want to get $_POST a variable from HTML and then parse it to an array. After that I want to save to database as much as the existing array. I was try but it still not work. Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php

if (isset ($_POST['submit']))
{
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","122333");

    if (!$con)
    {
    die ("sql error".mysqli_error());

    }

    mysql_select_db("test",$con);

    $jumlahProduk= array('$_POST[jumlah1]','$_POST[jumlah2]', 
                    '$_POST[jumlah3]','$_POST[jumlah4]','$_POST[jumlah5]');
     $jenisProduk= array('$_POST[jenis1]','$_POST[jenis2]' ,
                    '$_POST[jenis3]','$_POST[jenis4]','$_POST[jenis5]');

    for($i=1;$i<6;$i++){
        $sql="INSERT INTO ternak (id_peternak,
                                kode_produk,
                                peternak,
                                jumlah,
                                tgl_panen.
                                tgl_potong,
                                tgl_packing,
                                tgl_kadaluarsa)
                            VALUES($peternak_id,
                                $jenisProduk [$i],
                                '$_POST[peternak]',
                                $jumlahProduk [$i],
                                '$_POST[tgl_panen]',
                                '$_POST[tgl_potong]',
                                '$_POST[tgl_packing]',
                                '$_POST[tgl_kadaluarsa]')";
        $store_data=mysql_query($sql, $con);
    }
    mysql_close($con);
}
    ?>
```

From HTML's Form, I can get jumlah1,jumlah2,jumlah3,jumlah4,jumlah5 so on. Please help me.

Comment: Not only do you have lots of errors here, but you are using obsolete code and are wide open to sql injections.

Comment: i'm sory i'm a beginner in PHP, so what i have to do?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't use variables in single quotes in PHP.. They will be treated as strings.
2. $_POST[peternak] should be $_POST['peternak'] or  $_POST["peternak"]
3. You are mixing mysql_* and mysqli_* functions at the beginning. Considering you to use the new mysqli functions since the mysql functions are less secure and old.
4. Your for loop makes no sense to me. You are just looping through a constant limit. This could possibly lead to some sort of "out of bounds" error. You could use the length of your array to limit the loop.

I would recommend you to learn the basic syntax of PHP first.